# How to denote the rank-$3$-tensor $B$, where $Av\odot w = \langle B, w\rangle$.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, tensor-products

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, vectors $v,w \in \mathbb R^n$ and the symmetric tensor product
$$v \odot w := \frac12 (v\otimes w + w\otimes v) = \frac12 (vw^T + wv^T).$$

Then, for all indices $i,j$,

$$(Av\odot w)_{i,j} = \frac12((Av)_i w_j + w_i (Av)_j) = \frac12\sum_{k=1}^d A_{i,k} v_k w_j + w_i A_{j,k} v_k = \langle\frac12 ((A\otimes w)^{(23)} + (A\otimes w)^{(132)}),v\rangle,$$

where $\langle B, v\rangle_{i,j} := \sum_{k=1}^n B_{i,j,k} v_k$, $B^{\tau}$ is $B$ with its indices permuted by $\tau \in S_3$ (symmetric group on $3$ letters) and $A\otimes w$ is rank-$3$ tensor with $(A\otimes w)_{i,j,k} = A_{i,j} w_k$.

Is there a common way to denote the rank-$3$ tensor $B := \frac12 ((A\otimes w)^{(23)} + (A\otimes w)^{(132)})?$ Perhaps if you assume that $A$ is symmetric too?

$B$ sort of looks like a "partial symmetrization" of $A\otimes w$ if that makes any sense.